# Issue with Creating a Linked List

Tags: c++, class, pointers

First off, here is my code:

Part of Header File:

```
struct polynomial
{ 
    polynomial();
    polynomial(string newCoefficient, string newPower, polynomial *nextPtr);
    string coefficient;
    string power;
    polynomial *next; 
};

class linkedList
{
public:
    void makeList();
private:
    polynomial *head;
};
```

.cpp File:

```
polynomial:: polynomial ( string newCoefficient, string newPower, polynomial *nextPtr )
    :
coefficient(newCoefficient),
    power(newPower), 
    next(nextPtr) 

{}

void linkedList::makeList()
{
    polynomial poly; 

    string input1, input2; 
    cin >> input1; 
    cin >> input2;

    while (input1 != "-999" && input2 != "-999") 
    { 
        poly *newNode = new polynomial (input1, input2, next); 
        next = newNode; 
        cin >> input1;
        cin >> input2;
    }

}
```

However, the problem lies in these two lines of code:

```
poly *newNode = new polynomial (input1, input2, next); 
next = newNode;
```

In the first line, it says that newNode is an undeclared identifier. It also says:

Polynomial::polynomial(std::string,std::string,polynomial *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from '*InIt (*_cdecl *)(_InIt,iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type)' to 'polynomial *'
1>          Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

In line two, it says newNode is undeclared once again.

What is the issue here? :( I am trying to place values in the struct in the linked list. After coding a bit more, I want to create a new linked list whenever they input the two values.

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with linked lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never declared `next`, and `poly` is a variable, not a type. Should be `polynomial *poly`, then `poly = new polynomial(input1, input2, next);`.

Comment: LOL, I'm an idiot! Hahaha, thank you Jorge, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Happens to all of us. Glad I could help.